# How do I remove nth component inside of my return function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have a component that I am displaying 'n' times. There is also a button next to that 'nth' component so I can remove that component and the button when pressed. How would I go about doing this? This is my code where i'm displaying my component n times. I want the 'nth' component removed when the 'nth' button is pressed.

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-array-index-key */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, ArrayInput, SimpleFormIterator,
} from 'react-admin';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CreateAudienceLabelFromEntity from './CreateAudienceField';
import './audienceLabel.css';

const AudienceLabelCreate = (props) => {
  const [audienceLabelCount, setAudienceLabelCount] = useState(10);
  return (
    <div className="audienceLabelContainer">
      {[...Array(audienceLabelCount)].map((e, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="audienceLabelRow">
          <CreateAudienceLabelFromEntity />
          <Button className="removeLabel" variant="outlined">Remove</Button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudienceLabelCreate;
```

Comment: [Don't use array position](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) as your component key unless you have absolutely nothing else to use instead. As for removing elements when you click buttons: your button should not remove elements at all, you should have an array in your state, and your button should prune that array, so that the rerender simply shows the right thing. Instead of an `audienceLabelCount` state value, create an `audienceLabels` state array and work with that.

Comment: Can you show me a simple example? I'm a little confused in what to populate audienceLabels state array with.

Comment: This design seems fairly strange since it uses the number 10 rather than an array of items as you'd normally see. What's `<CreateAudienceLabelFromEntity />`? What distinguishes one element from another? Playing along with the design as is, you could create an array or set to keep track of which indices have been removed, but I smell a deeper design problem where data that should be coming down from the top or internal to this component is nested inside a child, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fill the state array with a simple object (that is issued an `id`), then you can just update this state however you want (like filter out the items you want):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const AudienceLabelCreate = ({ labelCount = 10 }) => {
  const [audienceLabelItems, setAudienceLabelItems] = useState([...Array(labelCount)].map((e, i) => ({ id: i })))

  // removing item from the list
  const onRemoveItem = ({ id }) => {
    setAudienceLabelItems((prevState) => {
      return prevState.filter(({ id: prevId }) => prevId !== id)
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        audienceLabelItems.map(({ id }) => {
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              {id}
              <button onClick={() => onRemoveItem({ id })}>REMOVE</button>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

// the labelCount prop can be set here,
// or the default is used that is set in
// the AudienceLabelCreate labelCount prop
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AudienceLabelCreate
        labelCount={15}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

## EDIT

If you want to create components where you can dynamically change the items (add/remove), then I suggest you update the structure: there should be a component that manages a list of items (audience labels); there should be an item that is a single label.

This way, the single label item doesn't have to know anything about the other labels, but the "manager" doesn't have to deal with how a single label is presented.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React
// just a way to generate IDs
// more on this: https://github.com/simplyhexagonal/short-unique-id
const uid = new ShortUniqueId({ length: 5 });

const DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_LABELS = 10

// this component is only responsible for:
// - displaying a single label row
// - passing the ID to the function it gets as a prop
const AudienceLabel = ({ labelId, removeLabel }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className='single-label-row'
    >
      <div
        className='single-label-inner'
      >
        {labelId}
        <button
          onClick={() => removeLabel({ id: labelId })}
        >
          REMOVE LABEL
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

// custom hook to manage labels; responsible for:
// - initialising the label list
// - managing the list of labels (by having the ADD/REMOVE functions)
const useAudienceLabels = () => {
  const [audienceLabels, setAudienceLabels] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setAudienceLabels(() => [...Array(DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_LABELS)].map(e => ({ id: uid() })) ) 
  }, [])

  const addSingleLabel = () => {
    setAudienceLabels(prevState => [...prevState, { id: uid() }])
  }
  
  const removeSingleLabel = ({ id }) => {
    setAudienceLabels(prevState => prevState.filter(({ id: prevId }) => prevId !== id))
  }

  return {
    audienceLabels,
    addSingleLabel,
    removeSingleLabel,
  }
}

// this is the audience label list "manager"
// this component is responsible for
// - displaying the children (single label rows)
const App = () => {
  const {
    audienceLabels,
    addSingleLabel: onAddSingleLabel,
    removeSingleLabel: onRemoveSingleLabel,
  } = useAudienceLabels()

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="label-list mb-4"
      >
        {
          audienceLabels.map(({ id }) => {
            return (
              <AudienceLabel
                key={id}
                labelId={id}
                removeLabel={onRemoveSingleLabel}
              />
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
      <button
        className="mt-4"
        onClick={onAddSingleLabel}
      >
        ADD NEW LABEL +
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.mb-4 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.label-list {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.single-label-row {
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.single-label-inner {
  margin: 4px 8px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/short-unique-id@4.4.4/dist/short-unique-id.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this also work if I had a button that would increment the 'labelCount' prop?

Comment: @TheCoder I added a new snippet where you can add/remove audience labels.

Comment: Wow thanks man your a life saver for that answer. I will be using it thank you!